# Zero sections of any smooth vector bundle is smooth?

Tags: differential-geometry

Could any one give me hint how to show that the zero section of any smooth vector bundle is smooth?

Zero section is a map $\xi:M\rightarrow E$ defined by $$\xi(p)=0\qquad\forall p\in M.$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Smoothness can be checked locally on $M$ and locally $E$ is trivial.

Can you use these two facts to conclude what you want?

Comment: @KutukKatuk If $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds and $p\in N$, then the inclusion $M\to M\times N$ given by the rule $m\to (m,p)$ is smooth. If you understand this and combine it with Mariano's answer, then you will have found an answer to your original question.

Comment: I am a little confused; do we explicitly use the mapping to zero in the proof? It seems like local triviality would apply no matter what constant vector we mapped to.

Comment: @Tarnation: but mapping to another «constant vector» would in general not give an actual section of the bundle: most vector bundles do not have non-zero sections! Zero is different: we always have the zero section.

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Álvarez Hi. Sorry if my question is a little silly. You say smoothness can be checked locally on $M$, can you explain this to me. Thanks.

Comment: @user9547, what I mean is that a function is smooth if it is locally smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Say $E\to M$ is a smooth vector bundle, and let $p\in M$. Then there is a neighborhood $U\subseteq M$ of $p$ and a smooth local trivialization $\Phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times\mathbb R^k$ of $E$ over $U$. What can you say about $(\Phi\circ\zeta)(q)$ where $q\in U$? Can you conclude that $\Phi\circ\zeta$ is smooth? Now remember that $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @user59083 Hi. I did what you say in your answer, but I get that $\xi$ is smooth in $U$. Maybe this is a silly question but how do I extent this to conclude smoothness in $M$?